# MySQL Timestamp how to write a query to select weekdays only

Tags: mysql

I want to write mysql for filter weekday result only. I used timestamp for store dates. can anyone help me to this?

eg; SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE WEEKDAY('mydate_field')

Comment: what's the problem? `where weekday(yourfield) = 3` would look for records with "wednesday" dates.

Comment: @MarcB I just want to filter all weekday result from table

Comment: @Gone no Monday to Friday

Answer (score 5):

Considering you mean excluding Sunday and Saturday.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE DAYOFWEEK('mydate_field') in (2,3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE WEEKDAY('mydate_field')<5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like this.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE WEEKDAY(mydate_field)>0 AND WEEKDAY(mydate_field)<6;
```

Comment: This is not correct. ```WEEKDAY()``` will return day index, starting from 0. So 
0 == Monday, and 4 == Friday. Correct one would be 
```SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE WEEKDAY(mydate_field)<5;  ```, like in @Gone answer.